# Format of Tracing output in System.Diagnostics.TraceSource

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics, tracesource

The following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("MyApplication");

    ts.Switch = new SourceSwitch("MySwitch");
    ts.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.All;

    ts.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));

    ts.TraceInformation("Hello World");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

generates the following output:

> MyApplication Information: 0 : Hello World

The part "MyApplication Information: 0 :" at the beginning of the trace output is coming from the TraceSource class itself.

However, I need to have a timestamp at the beginning of the line and I would like to change "Information" to "Info" also.

Is there any way to get more freedom in trace output such that I can configure it to be like:

> **13:03:00** - MyApplication **Info**: Hello World

I tried for a couple of hours, but with no success. Whatever I do, at the beginning of the output line, there is always this constant predefined "MyApplication Information: 0 : Hello World" output.

MSDN documentation did also not reveal any helpful information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the [TraceOutputOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.traceoutputoptions.aspx) property on the trace listener. The format is predefined, but you can opt-in for the additional pieces of data defined by the [TraceOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a10k7w6c.aspx) enum.

Comment: Tried it, but seems to be not the solution. With TraceOutputOptions, I can only specify which **additional** elements I want in my output. But actually I want **less**! ;)

Comment: Create your own trace listener inheriting from text writer listener and override the methods that do the formatting. Use that listener instead.

Answer (score 8):

Coming in late also but in case someone else lands here...

I like keeping it simple.  I use one static Trace method within my App.cs which ties to a single TraceSource that I create at start up.  This allows me access it throughout my app and keep the app.config simple:

```
public static void Trace(TraceEventType eventType, string message)
{
    if (_TraceSource.Switch.ShouldTrace(eventType))
    {
        string tracemessage = string.Format("{0}\t[{1}]\t{2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss"), eventType, message);
        foreach (TraceListener listener in _TraceSource.Listeners)
        {
            listener.WriteLine(tracemessage);
            listener.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

My app.config entries:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="mytracesource" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add name="mytracelistener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData="trace.log">
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 3):

[TraceSource.TraceInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky200w42.aspx) ends up calling [TraceListener.TraceEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa710ybd.aspx) on each listener which adds in the header. Fortunately, `TraceListener` has a [WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h418ytb.aspx) method which you can use to produce custom output.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("MyApplication");

    ts.Switch = new SourceSwitch("MySwitch");
    ts.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.All;

    ts.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));

    for (int i = 0; i < ts.Listeners.Count; i++)
    {
        var listener = ts.Listeners[i];

        listener.WriteLine(
            string.Format("{0} - {1} Info: {2}",
            DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), ts.Name, "Hello World"));
        listener.Flush();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

> **13:52:05** - MyApplication **Info**: Hello World

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late but if you want an easy and versatile solution you should have a look at the [Essentials Diagnostics](https://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex (also available [through NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Essential.Diagnostics/)).

It defines a wide range of listeners (with custom formatting allowed) that output to the console, rolling text and XML files, event logs, email, etc. and comes with configuration samples also.